# How to dynamically resize an iFrame (crossbrowser solution)

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, iframe, resize

I am trying to include an `iframe` on a Drupal page. So far I successfully included the frame but the height resize function that I wrote only works in Internet Explorer. My goal is to make resize work inFirefox and Chrome as well. I searched the Internet but I couldn't find what I was looking for. Long story short, I want my frame to automatically resize height itself.

This is what I did so far (this is the code of the HTML page included in Drupal):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resize() {
        var iframe = document.all.icw;
        document.getElementById("icw").style.height = iframe.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
</script>
<iframe id="icw" src="XXXXX" width="100%" scrolling="no" onload="resize()">
```

I understand that if the `iframe` lives on another domain the solution may be more difficult due to permissions. Is that correct?

These are the errors I get in Chrome and Firefox:

> Chrome: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
>
> Chrome: JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL XXX from frame with URL YYY. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
>
> Firefox: document.all is undefined

**EDIT:** What if I want to change one of the `iframe` element? In my case I need to change a textbox value. I understand I must do that when the page is loaded but I can't find a solution. No matter where I put the code I always a get a

> Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined

when I try to access the iFrame textbox.

**EDIT2:** Asked a new question since they weren't related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution works even cross-domain as long as you have access to both. There are a bunch of edge cases, but at least you can start with this. You can also add timer event to make sure iFrame is always a correct size so you never have scrollbar. Keep in mind this only works with browser supporting HTML5 due to the use of postMessage.

Inside iFrame

```
function resize(){
    var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement,
    height = body.offsetHeight;
    if(height === 0){
        height = html.offsetHeight;
    }
    parent.postMessage({'action':'RESIZE', 'height':height}, '*');
}
```

Parent

```
function handleMessage(e) {
    if (e.data.action == 'RESIZE') {
        var targetHeight = e.data.height;
        $('#iFrame').height(targetHeight);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
```

Comment: Nice job! It works like a charm with Firefox and Chrome, only problem is that it doesn't with IE. So I am trying to put an if into the resize function so that if browser is IE it uses the old method. Think it will work?

Answer (score 2):

```
window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
```

This code do not work for IE.

For IE use

```
window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleMessage, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this little library that does this and manages all the other edge cases for you.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer